# Simple rails filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have simplest rails app, with scaffold Tent

here my controller#index for

```
  def index
    @tents = Tent
    @tents = @tents.where(:brand => params[:brand]) if params[:brand]
    @tents = @tents.where(:season => params[:season]) if params[:season]
  end
```

view also standart, generated by scaffold

and here search witch should filter data

```
  = form_tag tents_path, method: :get do

    = label_tag "manufacturer"
    = select_tag :brand, options_for_select(...), include_blank: true

    = label_tag "seasons"
    - Tent.pluck(:season).each do |season|
      =check_box_tag 'season', season 
      =h season

    = submit_tag 'Submit'
```

**Problem 1:**

When i submit from, and params are unselected(select or checl_boxes) i don't want to send this params but they are sent with empty

`GET /tents?utf8=...&brand=&season=&commit=Submit`

**Problem 2:**

When i check multiple checkboxes get request is somthing like

`GET /tents?utf8=...&brand=Brand`**&season=4&season=3&**`commit=Submit`

after this i expect that data will be selected for both values, but controller expected that both values is in the field, and returns zero results

any suggestuions?

### **UPDATE**

probably my question solved in railscasts-111 (advanced search form)

Answer (score 0):

About problem 2:
You need to specify season checkbox like below:

```
     =check_box_tag 'season[]', season
```

But i didnt test it

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2:
You need to write javascript wrapper for form to serialize and send data on submit